# TypeError: Cannot read property 'sign' of undefined [JWT / Nestjs / e2e tests]

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nestjs-passport, nestjs-jwt

I need to generate a Jwt Bearer Token for my e2e tests.
As the process it a bit tedious, and because that's not what I am trying to test, I'd like to bypass it by directly getting instead of going through the 2FA real process.

Unfortunately I keep getting the following error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'sign' of undefined

      150 |
      151 |     function getBearerToken(candidateId: number) {
    > 152 |       return jwtService.sign({ sub: candidateId.toString() })
          |                         ^
      153 |     }
      154 |   })
      155 | })

      at getBearerToken (app.e2e-spec.ts:152:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app.e2e-spec.ts:127:21)
```

```
describe('Bookmarks Module', () => {
    let bearerToken: string
    let jwtService: JwtService

    beforeEach(() => {
      bearerToken = getBearerToken(1)
      jwtService = new JwtService({
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        signOptions: { expiresIn: '1h' },
      })
    })

    test('/v1/bookmarks/ (GET) [auth]', () => {
      return expectCorrectAuthenticatedGetResponse(
        `${V1_PREFIX}/bookmarks/`,
        bearerToken
      )
    })

    test('/v1/bookmarks/{id} (POST) [auth]', () => {
      const DATA = { offerId: 19 }
      return expectCorrectAuthenticatedPostResponse(
        `${V1_PREFIX}/bookmarks/${DATA.offerId}`,
        DATA,
        bearerToken
      )
    })

    function getBearerToken(candidateId: number) {
      return jwtService.sign({ sub: candidateId.toString() })
    }
  })
```

Comment: I'm not sure about it but aren't you required to `JwtModule.register` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `jwtService.sign()` in `getBearerToken()` which is itself called in `beforeEach()`, just before `jwtService` is initialized. So `jwtService` is still `undefined` when you try to use it. You should invert the lines in `beforeEach()`:

```js
    beforeEach(() => {
      jwtService = new JwtService({
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        signOptions: { expiresIn: '1h' },
      })
      bearerToken = getBearerToken(1)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue when I import `jwt` like:

`import { jwt } from "jsonwebtoken";`

So I changed it to:

`var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');`

or

`import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";`

and it worked it

I don't know why it worked.

Comment: Same thing. I have been trying to use ES6 modules and when I imported using the destructuring it gave this error. But using `require` or excluding the curly braces made it work again.

Comment: because of the node version.

Answer (score 0):

For me was a different issue. [node v18]

changed this:
`import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'` 
to this: 
`import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'` 
or each individual property:
`import {sign, verify, JwtPayload} from "jsonwebtoken";`

and back in business.